# Stubbing a service that returns resources with Sinon

Tags: angularjs, sinon

I've been stubbing and mocking services in Sinon, but it never worked for me when the service returns $resources. I need some help!

These are the services (first of which returning $resources):

```
    terminalService.factory('PrinterData', [ '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('ws/Admin/printer/data');
} ]);

terminalService.factory('PrinterService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    return {

                    test:function() {
                        $http({url: 'ws/Admin/printer/test',
                            method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}
                                ).then(function () {
                            return;
                        }); 
                    },

                    replacePaper : function() {
                        $http({url: 'ws/Admin/printer/replacePaper',
                            method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}
                                ).then(function () {
                            return;
                        }); 
                    },

                    setPrinter : function(jsonData) {

                        var req = {
                                 method: 'POST',
                                 url: 'ws/Admin/printer/set',
                                 headers: {
                                   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                                 },
                                 params: jsonData,
                                };

                        $http(req).success(function(){
                        });
                    }   
          }
}]);
```

This is my Controller that uses the services:

```
    terminalController.controller('PrinterTestController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'PrinterData', 'PrinterService',
                   function($rootScope, $scope, PrinterData, PrinterService) {

        $rootScope.currentPage = 'PRINTER_TEST';

        PrinterData.get().$promise.then(function (response) {
            $scope.printerData = response;
            $scope.printers = response.printers;
            $rootScope.ports = response.ports;
            $rootScope.printerSettings = response.printerSettings;
        });

        $scope.testPrinter = function() {
            PrinterService.test();
        };

        $scope.replacePaper= function() {
            PrinterService.replacePaper();
        };

        $scope.setPrinter = function() {
            var jsonData = {
                    settings: '{"model": "' + $rootScope.printerSettings.model + '","port":"'
                     + $rootScope.printerSettings.port + '","askClientPrintReceipt":"'
                     + $rootScope.printerSettings.askClientPrintReceipt + '"}'
            };
            PrinterService.setPrinter(jsonData);
        };
    }
]);
```

And finally my test:

```
describe('PrinterTestController', function() {

var rootScope, scope, stubbedPrinterData, q;

beforeEach(module('eshtaPayTerminalApp.controllers'));

fakePrinterService = {
        replacePaper : function() {},
        test: function(){},
        setPrinter : function(){}
      };

beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $q, PrinterData) {      
    q = $q;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    rootScope = $rootScope.$new();
    stubbedPrinterData = sinon.stub(PrinterData);

    $controller('PrinterTestController', {
        $rootScope : rootScope,
        $scope : scope,
        PrinterData : stubbedPrinterData,
        PrinterService : fakePrinterService
    });     
}));
it('should not fail', function(){
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

The service that returns $resources is always throwing: 
 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/unpr?p0=PrinterDataProvider%20%3C-%20PrinterData

Can anyone help?

Comment: When you are stubbing, don't you have to set the return using `returns(value)`? The error doesn't match up with the code you posted. What is `PhoneDataController`?

Comment: Was a typo sorry about that... I updated.